# How to generate working service worker with workbox and webpack?

Tags: webpack, workbox

I'm trying to build my first PWA but I'm struggling to get things up and running.
I've been adding the "GenerateSW" to my webpack.prod.js like so:

```
const { GenerateSW } = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
...
    plugins: [
...
new GenerateSW()
]
...
```

The build process generates a service-worker.js containing many entries, but from what I can see it does not contain the vendor.bundle.js

Should it contain all generated js files or is it correct that the vendor.bundle.js is missing?
When launching the app I can find some pre-cached files in the "Cache Storage/workbox-precache-v2" but the vendor.bundle.js is also missing there.
It contains the main.bundle.js though but when switching to offline and reloading the page I see that the main.bundle.js is also not getting loaded:
main.bundle.js?06c1420d003c1b00a02a (failed)
Is it because webpack adds a URL parameters when loading the bundle?

The PWA manifest also fails to load, probably because the service worker fails to start?

Answer (score 2):

I had to increase the filesize of objects to be pre-cached like this:

```
new GenerateSW({
    maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes : 5000000
})
```